# Can not instantiate proxy of class error when writing unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following classes:

```
   public ExtractUkFileFunction (UkExtractFileHandler fileHandler)
        {
            _fileHandler = fileHandler;
        }
```

and

```
public class UkExtractFileHandler : ExtractFileHandler<UkExtractFileHandler.FileMapper>
{
    public UkExtractFileHandler(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IRecordParser recordParser, IUnzipper unzipper, IFileStore fileStore, ILocationService locationService) 
        : base(recordParser, unzipper, fileStore, locationService)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory.Create<ExtractFileHandler>();
    }
```

As a starting point for my unit tests I just want to build this class/check that it can be built. I've tried the following:

```
 [Test]
    public void Construct_ExtractUkFileFunction_ExpectSuccess()
    {
        var mockLoggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
        var mockRecordParser = new Mock<IRecordParser>();
        var mockUnzipper = new Mock<IUnzipper>();
        var mockFileStore = new Mock<IFileStore>();
        var mockLocationService = new Mock<ILocationService>();
        
        var mockFileHandler = new Mock<ExtractFileHandler>
            (mockLoggerFactory.Object, mockRecordParser.Object, mockUnzipper.Object, mockFileStore.Object, mockLocationService.Object);
        var extractUkFileFunction = new ExtractUkFileFunction(mockFileHandler.Object);

        Assert.IsNotNull(extractUkFileFunction ); 
    }
```

However I receive the error:

```
Can not instantiate proxy of class: Core.Handlers.UkExtractFileHandler.
    Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
    Castle.Proxies.ILoggerFactoryProxy
    Castle.Proxies.IRecordParserProxy
    Castle.Proxies.IUnzipperProxy
    Castle.Proxies.IFileStoreProxy
    Castle.Proxies.ILocationServiceProxy
```

I do not have lots of experience with C# unit testing or Moq, so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the problem is caused by the version of Moq you are using and the target framework of your test. Are you using .net or .net core?

Comment: You have `UkExtractFileHandler`, but mock `ExtractFileHandler`. How does `ExtractFileHandler` look like?

Comment: apologies that was a typo @PavelAnikhouski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provided for UkExtractFileHandler :

```
public class UkExtractFileHandler : ExtractFileHandler<UkExtractFileHandler.FileMapper>
{
    public UkExtractFileHandler(
          ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
          IRecordParser recordParser, 
          IUnzipper unzipper, 
          IFileStore fileStore, 
          ILocationService locationService) 
        : base(recordParser, unzipper, fileStore, locationService)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory.Create<ExtractFileHandler>();
    }
}
```

would the base class of UkExtractFileHandler look somehow like this:

```
    public class ExtractFileHandler<T>
    {
        public ExtractFileHandler(
            IRecordParser recordParser, 
            IUnzipper unzipper, 
            IFileStore fileStore, 
            ILocationService locationService)                 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

But in the unit test you mock class ExtractFileHandler so I suppose you have something like this in your code:

```
public class ExtractFileHandler<T> : ExtractFileHandler
{

}
```

and it is obvious from UkExtractFileHandler  class that ExtractFileHandler has a constructor like this *with 4 parameters*:

```
public class ExtractFileHandler
{
    public ExtractFileHandler(
        IRecordParser recordParser, 
        IUnzipper unzipper, 
        IFileStore fileStore, 
        ILocationService locationService)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So your problem could be in this code where you pass *not 4 but 5 parameters* to constructor of ExtractFileHandler which expects *only 4 parameters*:

```
var mockFileHandler = new Mock<ExtractFileHandler>(
   mockLoggerFactory.Object, <- this par. probably doesn't match the constructor signature 
   mockRecordParser.Object, 
   mockUnzipper.Object, 
   mockFileStore.Object, 
   mockLocationService.Object);
```

When the number of parameters used doesn't match in Mock like in this case you will receive the exception of type Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException:

> Can not instantiate proxy of class ... Could not find a constructor
> that would match given arguments